# How to migrate object storage from one instance to another in IBM cloud?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-storage

i am trying to migrate object storage from ibm cloud's one account to another account.I am trying to use rclone but it is very confusing.Please some one help me with proper steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IBM App Connect to move all data from a partner cloud storage system like Amazon S3 to Cloud Object Storage or in the same cloud between Cloud storages

> Suppose your organization needs to move all data from a partner cloud
> storage system like Amazon S3 to Cloud Object Storage. This task
> involves the transfer of a large amount of data. By using a batch
> retrieve operation in App Connect, you can extract all the files from
> an Amazon S3 bucket and upload them to a Cloud Object Storage bucket.
> Before you start: This article assumes that you’ve created accounts
> for Amazon S3 and Cloud Object Storage.

Follow the [instructions in this post](https://developer.ibm.com/integration/blog/2019/07/18/data-migration-between-amazon-s3-and-ibm-cloud-object-storage-using-ibm-app-connect/) and just replace Amazon S3 instance with IBM Cloud Object storage from where you want to migrate the data from